# Print output of println command to a file in a Jenkins job

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

```
commitHash = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git log --pretty=format:'%H|%an|%ae|%ah|%s' -5 | column -t -s '|'")
println commitHash
```

I can see the output of the `commitHash` in the Jenkins job console output, but I need to save this output to a file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Jenkins step [writeFile](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#writefile-write-file-to-workspace):

```
writeFile(file: "myFile.txt", text: commitHash)
```